# How to use the module(speech recognition) with microphone to transform instantly

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, google-speech-api

```
import speech_recognition

r= speech_recognition.Recognizer()

with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
    print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...") 
    #listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level 
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5) 
    print("Say something!")
    audio= r.listen(source)

print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said:")    
result=r.recognize_google(audio, language="zh-TW")
print(result)
```

How to use the module(speech recognition) with microphone to transform instantly.
I try this module to transform the voice from computer microphone to script, but it just can transform when the whole sentence is said.
Can it transform instantly word by word?

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Thanks,I have provided.